# Error when connection .NET WCF service on https

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-config

I am trying to connect to a WCF service over https and i get the following error

An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://mysite/App/Service/MyService.svc.
This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Please help me out of this issue. We need to move to prod by weekend.

WCF web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections><sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
<sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
<section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
</sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
<add key="MyEnv" value="Server01" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
</assemblies>
<buildProviders><add extension=".rpt" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" /></buildProviders>
</compilation>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<pages>
<namespaces>
<add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
<add namespace="System.ServiceModel" />
<add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
</namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<add value="MyService.svc" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
<businessObjects><crystalReports><rptBuildProvider><add embedRptInResource="true" /></rptBuildProvider></crystalReports></businessObjects></configuration>
```

Web Application web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="HelpLoadMode" value="All" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="35"></sessionState>    
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</assemblies>
</compilation>
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IReportService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
maxBufferSize="4194304" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"
messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
useDefaultWebProxy="true">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="6400" maxStringContentLength="4194304" maxArrayLength="131072"
maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
<security mode="Transport">
<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
</binding>
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService1" />
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>      
<endpoint address="https://mysite/App/Service/MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
contract="MyService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
</client>
<standardEndpoints>
<webHttpEndpoint>
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
</webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>       
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<caching>
<profiles>
<add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
<add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
<add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
<add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
</profiles>
</caching>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />       
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Incidentally, I notice that the `<compilation>` section has `strict="false"`. That is not good. Some time should be assigned to set [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) and correct any problems it highlights.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCF configuration only supports HTTP protocol to expose the service, we need to set up the additional service endpoint in the System.ServiceModel section.
Please consider the below configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then we specify an https binding in IIS.
[image]
After publishing the service in IIS, we add the service reference on the client to generate the client proxy. It would auto-generate the https endpoint.
[image]
One thing must be noted is that we should trust the server certificate when calling the service with the HTTPS endpoint on the server-side.
There are two ways to accomplished this.

1. Use the below code segments before instantiating the client proxy
   class.

   ```
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
               {
                   return true;
               };
   ```
2. Install the server certificate on the client-side Trusted Root
   Certification Authorities(certificate store).

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.